# How is req and res accessible accross modules in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

While using express.js for handling various routes I want to encapsulate all of my route code in a separate module, but how can I access the req and res object across modules? See the code below.
The main file examples.js is written as follows:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var login = require('./login.js');
app.get('/login', login.auth(app.req, app.res));
app.listen(80);
```

What I want is that the login handling code be written in a separate module/file called login.js. The question then is how will the response object be accessible in login.js? I think the following code will not work as because the type of req and res is not resolved.

```
exports.auth = function(req, res) {
    res.send('Testing');
}
```

Hence when I start the server with node example.js I get the error:

'Cannot call method send of undefined'

How is the Request and Response objects passed along modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
app.get('/login', login.auth);
```

Your example was attempting to pass the return value of the `login.auth` function as get handler for the request. The above instead passes the `login.auth` function itself as the handler.

Comment: Oh yes, such a silly mistake, app.get is supposed to just register the call back and not execute it

Comment: @Raks: Please accept this as an answer (click on the tick on the right)

Answer (score 0):

TJ Holowaychuk made some great examples for express on the github page, here's the one about route separation:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation