# How to define the "req" and the "res" in the middleware object?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, middleware

Good day! I saw here the answer on a similar question([How is req and res accessible accross modules in Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702509/)), but the date of this answer is Apr2011... The situation in this question is very similar, but, how I think, I started from the point, which was suggested in those answer - and it did not work. And in those answer was used the `exports.something=` instead of the `module.exports`. In many tutorials I read, that the using of the `module.exports` is better, but forgot why:) Just for information - I use the express 4.x, Node 4.5.x. So I'll try expound my problem laconically, provide the comments and describe the behavior:

I have a simple experimental app.

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin
├── config
├── createDb.js
├── error
├── libs
├── middleware
├── models
├── node_modules
├── ownroutes
├── package.json
├── public
├── routes
└── views
```

In `error` directory I created a file with a customError, which exports to the `routes` directory:

```
// CustomError file

    var path = require('path');
    var util = require('util');
    var http = require('http');

    function HttpError(status, message){
        Error.apply(this, arguments);
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, HttpError);

        this.status = status;
        this.message = message || http.STATUS_CODES[status] || "Error";
    }

    util.inherits(HttpError, Error);
    HttpError.prototype.name = "HttpError";
    module.exports = HttpError;
```

In `middleware` directory I attempted to create a ErrorHandling middleware, but it does not work. My ErrorHandling function exports to the `routes` directory too:

```
// ErrorHanling middleware file

    function httpErrorHandler(err, req, res, next){
        console.log("THIS IS REQUEST" +req+ "END OF REQUEST"); //just for checking

        res.sendHttpError = function(err){
            console.log("THIS IS RESPONSE" +res+ "END OF RESPONSE");//just for checking too
            res.status(error.status);
            if (res.req.headers['x-requested-with'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'){
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                res.render("error", {error: error, message: "ALL RIGHT!!!!"});
            }
        };

        next();
    };

    module.exports = httpErrorHandler;
```

And, finally, the `index.js` in `routes` directory:

```
//Router
//The problematical piece of code is here - see comments below

        var express = require('express');
        var router = express.Router();
        var User = require('../models/user');
        var HttpError = require('../error/index'); // CustomError!!!!!!!!
        var httpErrorHandler = require('../middleware/sendHttpError'); //ErrorHandling middleware!!!!!!
        var util = require("util");


            router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
                res.render("templ");
            });


            router.get('/users', function(req, res, next){

                User.find({}, function(err, users){
                    if(err) return next(err);
                    res.json(users);        
                })

            })

     //Now I pass the User with incorrectID for occuring of the CustomError

            router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res, next){
                User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user){
                    if(err) return next(err);
                    if(!user){
                        next(new HttpError(404, "User Not Found"));
                    }
                    res.json(user); 
                })

            });

      //The problematical piece of code

        router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
            if(typeof err == 'numder'){
                err = new HttpError(err); // this is a CustomError
            }
            if (err instanceof HttpError){
                console.log('TRUE'); // I have "TRUE" in the console
                httpErrorHandler();
            }
            if(err == "CastError"){
                console.log("CastError");
            }else{
                console.log('BLAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
            }

            next();
        });

        module.exports = router;
```

The `router` works correctly, but when I try get the User with incorrectID, I have a message in the console:`TypeError: Cannot set property 'sendHttpError' of undefined`. So, obviously, the "response" is "undefined" and "request" is "undefined" too. The adding of this code into the ErrorHandling middleware file for defining the `req` and the `res`:

```
var express = require('express');
var req = express.request;
var res = express.response;
console.log(req); // the "req" object is visible here, but invisible in the function
```

is not helpful.

And when I set the whole ErrorHandling function into the place, where the `TRUE` in the `Router`, directly, the Error handles correctly.

If I call the `HttpErrorHandler()` function with `err, req, res, next` in a `Router`, I have `BLAAAA` in the console and redirection to the `/`. Why my CustomError does not occur and who does this redirection: the `next()` in the middleware, or the `next()` in the `Router`?

I exactly understand that the `req` and `res` must be define, but how to define them in the middleware ErrorHandling function? Can I to consider this approach of building of the applications as a proper decision (modularity) or may be the ErrorHandling object more better to set in the router directly?

Comment: Rule of thumb i follow is to use exports.foo when you want to export an instance of the module, use module.exports when you want to export an object, e.g. revealing module pattern.

Comment: Did you read the [Express Error Handling Guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)?

Comment: @peteb thank you. I used your advice, but I just thought before that the Router itself must have some logic for using appropriate middleware for handling of the certain Errors, but this logic, actually, must to be set in the middleware itself.